# Show soft keybord on edit text in a tab with multiple activities?

Tags: android

I am using multiple activities in my tab activity. There is an edit text field in my first activity under the first tab, but when I move from first activity within the first tab to the second activity and when I go back to my first activity using replaceview property and pressing the hardware back button, my edit text field do not show the softinputkeyboard.

What should I do in this? I used onResume this code, but still not working.

```
edittext.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.showSoftInput(etSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think no need to use replace view if you want to go back to previous activity inside Tab group.

Comment: but I have to, as I want to display the same tab for each activity inside that particular tab.

Comment: ya you can do this using TabGroupActivity, which allow us to navigate among different activities and maintain stack of activity in order to handle back button click and other stuffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because edittext.requestFocus() does not focus the element immediately.

try this approach:

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        if(hasFocus)
        {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.showSoftInput(etSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try this inside if(hasFocus) `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);`